# Read and write to a buffer in a fragment shader

Tags: c++, glsl, fragment-shader, vulkan

I'm trying to use a buffer in a fragment like an append buffer : for each execution of the fragment shader, I get the offset of the buffer, add the data and increment the offset.

```
#version 450
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable

layout(location = 0) in vec2 inPosition;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

layout(std140, binding = 0) buffer CommandDraw {
    uint indexCount;
    uint instanceCount;
    uint firstIndex;
    int vertexOffset;
    uint firstInstance;
};

layout(std430, binding = 1) buffer SSBO {
    float data[];
};

void addVertex(vec4 pos, vec4 color)
{
    uint id = indexCount++;
    uint offset = id * 8;

    data[offset] = pos.x;
    data[offset + 1] = pos.y;
    data[offset + 2] = pos.z;
    data[offset + 3] = pos.w;

    data[offset + 4] = color.x;
    data[offset + 5] = color.y;
    data[offset + 6] = color.z;
    data[offset + 7] = color.w;
}

void main() 
{
    vec3 color = vec3(0.0);
    addVertex(vec4(inPosition, 0.0, 1.0), vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0));

    outColor = vec4(inPosition / 2.0 + vec2(0.5), 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

I execute the fragment shader with a full screen quad.
The problem is that the final offset (here `indexCount`) is too low : it should be equal to `width * height` but the value is lower (around `60` for a extent equal to `1280 * 720`).

I think that the problem is due to the parallel execution of the fragment shader : some fragment maybe use the same buffer at the same time.

My question is : is it possible to "lock" the resource like with a `std::mutex` to avoid fragment using the same resource at the same time ?

Comment: "*`#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable`*" Why are you enabling an extension that has been core OpenGL since 4.2?

Comment: I didn't know. Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for a mutex; simply use an [atomic increment of the index value](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object#Atomic_operations):

```
uint id = atomicAdd(indexCount, 1);
```

All of those atomic functions return the previous value. So your code should be fine.

And there's really no point in making your output SSBO if you're not going to compress the data at all (that is, if you're just writing floats). It's better to make it mirror the types of variables you're writing:

```
struct Vertex
{
  vec4 pos;
  vec4 color;
};

layout(std430, binding = 1) writeonly restrict buffer SSBO {
    Vertex vertices[];
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works perfectly but I changed the syntax `layout(std430, writeonly, restrict, binding = 1) buffer SSBO` to `layout(std430, binding = 1) writeonly restrict buffer SSBO`. Using your syntax I get this error : `syntax error, unexpected WRITEONLY` .